# foreachRDD dont't execute

Tags: java, foreach, spark-streaming, rdd

Why the foreachRDD isn't execute?
This is the code, the part that isn't execute start at stream.foreachRDD and finish at });. Thanks for the answers ;).

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaCustomReceiver").setMaster("local[2]");
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(1));

        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.0.4.215:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream");
        //kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        //kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
        System.out.println(" 1");
        Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("test");

        JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
                KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                        ssc,
                        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                        ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
                );
        System.out.println(" 2");
        //stream.mapToPair(record -> new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value()));
        stream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumerRecordJavaRDD) throws Exception {
                List<ConsumerRecord<String,String>> l=consumerRecordJavaRDD.collect();
                System.out.println(" 3");
                for (ConsumerRecord<String,String> a: l) {
                    String stringa=a.value();
                    System.out.println("STRING: "+a);
                }
            }
        });
        System.out.println(" 4");
```

Comment: Does the end of code have ssc.start();ssc.awaitTermination() ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to consume the stream, otherwise it will never be executed - as far es i know.
Example: [Spark Doku](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations)